# Are web sockets a browser feature or supplied by a specific OS version?

Tags: javascript, web-development, web-applications, websockets

Are web sockets a web browser feature, developed and evolving as the browser developers want, or this feature dependent on the OS version?

For example, can I use this feature in JavaScript in IE and other browsers from Windows 8 only?

If it is a browser feature, which versions is it stable in Chrome, Mozilla, Opera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

webSocket is implemented in browsers (not in the underlying OS).  It is built on top of TCP/IP which comes from the OS.

You can see which versions of which browsers support webSockets here:http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: you mean that it's not dependent on OS. Even on Windows XP I can install latest mozilla, and websocket will be work, yes? Your second sentense confused me :d Also, thanks for the grat web-site!

Comment: @AlexLL - All versions of OSes have TCP/IP which is the only thing webSockets need from the OS.  So, yes you can run the latest Firefox on XP (if Firefox chooses to support XP) and webSockets will work there.